# Does the staking pool deposit of 500ADA count towards the stake?

Tags: stake-pool

Does the staking pool deposit of 500ADA count towards the total stake of the pool, or is it a separate deposit that does not count towards the total stake?

Comment: I would recommend expanding the text in your question's body.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I have worded it a little better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is a separate deposit which will be returned when the pool is retired.

Comment: So to clarify it does not count towards the total staked amount of the stake pool? That's disappointing. I have more than enough to cover it but it would definitely reduce my total stake substantially and hinder my ability to mint blocks.

Comment: That is correct. You will need around 1 million staked to average 1 block per epoch. There will be many epochs with zero, 2 and even 3 but it will average.

Comment: Haha well I have nowhere near that amount! I've read that a block can net around 1000 ADA or more depending on fees in the block. I only have a couple of thousand ADA. With the staking rewards I currently get can I deduce the probability of minting a block? Say if I get 100ADA/year, could I deduce that with my stake alone I would have to run a pool for up to 10 years to mint a single block?

Comment: Something along those lines. pool operator rewards on one block with 340 and 1% is around 380 ada. Luck is a factor as well. If I make 3 when I should make one I get more.

Comment: Yeah so it's more or less like trying to mine proof of work coins solo, you may get one in the end but you'll need to wait a lot of time and spend a lot of money to do so. And it won't even cover the 10-15k of server costs you spend doing it haha. Damn well that puts that dream to bed. If only I had a few friends with a million ADA!

Comment: Theres a cheaper way! armada-alliance.com. So cheap you can run an active relay and learn how to use the software for around $150

Comment: That's really interesting, I'll look into it. I guess there key here is I'm going to have to attract as many delegates as possible, maybe I'll reach out to a few forums and see if I can attract people who want to join a fixed fee only pool or start a community pool. Thanks so much for your help mate, it's people like you that make the cardano community great!